# Set Value and Label to JComboBox

Tags: java, swing, label, jcombobox

I have a JComboBox where the items are the results of a query. The combo shows all the categories names taken from a query, right? Ok, it works. Now I need to give each item a value, which would be the ID of the product.

This is what I've got so far:

```
    final JComboBox proveedorCombo = new JComboBox();

    contentPanel.add(proveedorCombo);

    ProveedorDAO dao = new ProveedorDAO();

    List<Proveedor> proveedor = dao.getAll();

    Object[][] elementos = new Object[proveedor.size()][2];

    for (int i = 0; i < proveedor.size(); i++) {
        Proveedor p = proveedor.get(i);
        elementos[i][0] = p.getId();
        elementos[i][1] = p.getNombre();
        proveedorCombo.addItem(elementos[i][1]);
    }
```

As you can see in the code, the "label" of each item is the name of it. Now, how can I set each item its ID so I can manipulate after?

Thanks and try to answer easily, I'm having the hardest time trying to get this Java thing! Ha!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JComboBox` by default uses a renderer wich uses `toString()` method to display object data. So you can make your own render class to customize the view.

This is the way it was designed for.

```
proveedorCombo.setRenderer( new DefaultListCellRenderer(){

        @Override  
        public Component getListCellRendererComponent(
            JList list, Object value, int index,
            boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus)
        {
            super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index,
                isSelected, cellHasFocus);

                if(value != null){
                 Proveedor proveedor = (Proveedor)value;
                 setText( proveedor.getName());
                }
            return this;
        }
});
```

Another hacky approach is overriding `toString()` from `Proveedor` or making your adapter class that uses your `toString()` but this solution is not much flexible as the other one.

```
public class Proveedor {

//in some part
@Override
public String toString(){
    return this.nombre;
}

}
```

In the combobox if you want to populate from zero.

```
proveedorCombo.setModel(new DefaultComboBox(new Vector<Proveedor>(dao.getAll())));
```

Or if you have previous data and you want to maintain.

```
for(Proveedor p : dao.getAll){
    proveedorCombo.addItem(p);
}
```

Comment: -1 for overriding toString for _view_ reasons, the way to go is a custom renderer

Comment: Yeah you got it right ... i take the easy way i put adapter class as render but never an example i'll edit

Comment: nice try - just not good enough when I'm on a quest against dirty approaches <g> _Two options_ means that both would be approximately on the same level of recommendability (huch .. is that a word?, too lazy to ask Leo) - which here definitely isn't the case, with one being the way it was designed and the other a quick&dirty hack which is a dead end in any but the most trivial contexts

Comment: @kleopatra how are you? Please read this [camick comment](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19919699/2415194) ,as i understood he is not disagree using `toString()` as far i understood that comment, what do you think?