# Editing how file name is displayed in JComboBox while maintaining access to file

Tags: java, swing, file, jcombobox

I am very new to Java and brand new to stack overflow.

I am attempting to create a simple media player coded in Java utilizing the JMF API. Thus far I have been able to set up a simple queue/playlist to hold song files using a `JComboBox` called `playListHolder`. When the user selects open from the menu bar, they select a song they want to add from a `JFileChooser`. The song file is then added to `playListHolder` using the `addItem()` method. When an item is selected in `playListHolder` and the user clicks the `play` button, a File object file is assigned the item to be played using `playListHolder.getSelectedItem()`. Section of code and relevant variables below:

```
File file;

Player p;

Component cont;

Container c;

Component visual;

JButton play = new JButton("Play");

play.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                file = (File) playListHolder.getSelectedItem();
                startplay();
            }
        }); 
public void openFile() { 
                JFileChooser filech = new JFileChooser();

        int result = filech.showOpenDialog(this);

        if (result == JFileChooser.CANCEL_OPTION) {
            file = null;
        } else {
            file = filech.getSelectedFile();
            playListHolder.addItem(file);
            ;
        }
    }


public void startplay() {

        if (file == null)
            return;
        removepreviousplayer();
        try {
            p = Manager.createPlayer(file.toURI().toURL());
            p.addControllerListener(new ControllerListener() {
                public void controllerUpdate(ControllerEvent ce) {
                    if (ce instanceof RealizeCompleteEvent) {
                        c = getContentPane();
                        cont = p.getControlPanelComponent();
                        visual = p.getVisualComponent();
                        if (visual != null)
                            c.add(visual, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                        if (cont != null)
                            c.add(cont, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
                        c.doLayout();
                    }
                }
            });
            p.start();
        }

        catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Invalid file or location",
                    "Error loading file", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

        }
    }
```

What I would like to do, is have the song files appear in the `JComboBox` with just the filename, not the entire path that the `file.toString()` sets up in the `JComboBox`.

Thus far, I tried just adding the `file.getName()` to the box, but quickly realized my noobishness. Doing this only adds a `String` of the file name to the box, such that when you use the `play` button in the media player to actually playback the file, it fails to find the file and throws an exception.

I also tried creating a `FileWrapper` class that had a `toString()` method which utilized the `file.getName()` method to return just the file name, and then added that `FileWrapper` to the box instead of the file object directly. I got the same result.

I am certain that it is just my amateur level of knowledge that is creating this stumbling block, there has to be a simple way to do this, but believe it or not I could not seem to find one, at lest not one written in a way I easily understood. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Your post is too large, but i think you need a `ListCellRenderer`

Comment: `I also tried creating a FileWrapper class that had a toString() method which utilized the file.getName() method to return just the file name,` - that should work.

Comment: Sorry for the length, I felt it better to explain too much rather not enough. @camickr When I tried using the FileWrapper idea, I got the same exception thrown when trying to play back the item. I was really surprised because I felt so dang clever with that one and it seemed to fail any way.

Comment: I will do some research on ListCellRenderer and see what I come up with. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what are you looking for, make a custom renderer for your comboBox

```
myComboBox.setRenderer( new DefaultListCellRenderer(){

        @Override  
        public Component getListCellRendererComponent(
            JList list, Object value, int index,
            boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus)
        {
            super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index,
                isSelected, cellHasFocus);
                if(value == null){
                     return this;    
                }

                if(value instanceof File){
                  File song = (File)value;
                  setText(song.getName());
                }else{
                  setText(value.toString());
                }
            return this;
        }
});
```

Read more [How to use ComboBox](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html)

Comment: Nit Pick: Doing a blind cast of an `Object` is a good idea ;)

Comment: Worked like a charm! Now to set myself to the task of fully understanding why it works. That link is very helpful, I was reading the JComboBox JavaDoc. Needless to say, it did not help me much. lol Thanks.

Comment: @ChrisSalgado, and my standard comment when you use a custom renderer is that you now break the functionality of the combo box because you can no longer select items from the combo box by entering the first character of the displayed names.

Comment: @MadProgrammer i don't get what you try to say

Comment: @camickr when i used a wrapper class overriding `toString` kleopatra says it was not a good idea cause swing was designed to use with renderers, see this similar [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18024246/set-value-and-label-to-jcombobox/18024727#18024727)

Comment: `File song = (File)value;` is a blind cast from `Object` to `File`, you've made no assertion over the type `Object` before you attempted the cast, this could potentially lead to `ClassCastException`s...

Comment: @MadProgrammer he said that he has File :D was an assumption

Comment: @nachokk Never assume that people know what they are doing.  The OP might "accidently" put a `String` into the list ;)

Comment: @nachokk Shame for the other people who might want to use your example in the mean time :(

Comment: @nachokk Now you got a potential `NullPointerExcepiton` hehehehe ;)

Comment: @nachokk That makes a nice change :P

Comment: @MadProgrammer In this case the code would only be handling files. You're right though, don't assume I know what I'm doing, because I don't. lol I am getting more comfortable in Java but still have plenty to learn. Despite the two above mentioned issues which I will keep in mind, this code works well for what I want to achieve.

Comment: @nachokk If I'm not getting any up-votes, I need to hold you to a high standard ;)

Comment: @nachokk Good edit! I was just staring at the code thinking about how to fix that potential problem when, I saw the update.

Comment: @ChrisSalgado I don't trust any one, especially myself ;)

Comment: I know she disagrees. I believe a GUI is built for the user, not the programmer. So breaking standard functionality is not a good solution to me. So, if you want to use a custom renderer then you also need a custom KeySelectionManager for the combo box. If you don't provide this, then I believe a wrapper class with a custom toString() is a better solution then having broken functionality. Just my two cents.

Comment: @camickr I failed to successfully implement the wrapper class idea previously. Not to say it doesn't work, but I failed in getting it to work. Your tip about the custom KeySelectionManager is appreciated. No harm in making things work better.

Answer (score 1):

Formatting content on the screen often falls to a renderer.  In this case a `ListCellRenderer`.

Take a look at [How to use combo boxes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html) and in particualr [Providing a Custom Renderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html#renderer)

Comment: upvoted, hhah you are like my jedimaster or perhaps a sithmaster :O

Comment: @nachokk Only because other people were good enough to do the same to me ;)