# How to set Label as Display and value as value in JCombobox in Swing?

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

My code dynamically creates `Jcombobox` and populates items from a query Result.
This query returns an Object which includes label and value.
I want to display label and returns value when calling `combo.getSelectedItem()`.
I saw this  [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18024246/set-value-and-label-to-jcombobox)
while searching, but I didn't get the idea.

```
JComboBox<String> jComboBox=new JComboBox<String>();

if(dataSourceAttributeObjs!=null && dataSourceAttributeObjs.size()>0)
{
    jComboBox.addItem("Select");
    for(DataSourceAttributeObj dataSourceAttributeObj:dataSourceAttributeObjs)
    {
        jComboBox.addItem(dataSourceAttributeObj.getLabel());
    }
}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).  Hard code some data in the example, to replace the DB.

Comment: You may also want to say precisely what's wrong with your code. Do you get an error (and which one) or are you getteng the wrong combobox ?

Comment: how to implement value property to this code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The example you mentioned ([Set Value and Label to JComboBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18024246/set-value-and-label-to-jcombobox)) describes the possibility to define a custom renderer for a combo box, which seems to be the right approach in your case.

The answer from [nachokk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2415194/nachokk) in a piece of code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class CustomComboBoxRenderer {
    public static void main(final String[] arguments) {
        new CustomComboBoxRenderer().launchGui();
    }

    private void launchGui() {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Stack Overflow: custom combo box renderer");
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 800, 600);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        final JComboBox<Concept> comboBox = getComboBox();
        final JLabel label = new JLabel("Please make a selection...");

        comboBox.addActionListener(actionEvent -> {
            final Object selectedItem = comboBox.getSelectedItem();
            if (selectedItem instanceof Concept)
                label.setText(((Concept) selectedItem).getValue());
        });

        final JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        panel.add(comboBox, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        panel.add(label, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JComboBox<Concept> getComboBox() {
        final List<Concept> concepts = Arrays.asList(new Concept("label 1", "value 1"),
                                                     new Concept("label 2", "value 2"),
                                                     new Concept("label 3", "value 3"));

        final JComboBox<Concept> comboBox = new JComboBox<>(new Vector<>(concepts));

        comboBox.setRenderer(new DefaultListCellRenderer() {
            @Override
            public Component getListCellRendererComponent(final JList<?> list,
                                                          final Object value,
                                                          final int index,
                                                          final boolean isSelected,
                                                          final boolean cellHasFocus) {
                super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected,
                                                   cellHasFocus);
                if (value instanceof Concept)
                    setText(((Concept) value).getLabel());

                return this;
            }
        });

        return comboBox;
    }
}
```

And the `Concept` class could look like this:

```
public class Concept {
    private final String label;
    private final String value;

    public Concept(String label, String value) {
        this.label = label;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getLabel() {
        return label;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Comment: When creating `JComboBox`, I recommend to override `setSelectedItem()`, or when you click on the cell, the dropdownlist will not be able to locate the right item in the list. the parameter passed to `setSelectedItem()` can be `Concept` or `String`, so be careful to deal with these two types of parameters.

Answer (score 0):

This will help you

public class Java extends JFrame {

```
private JComboBox cb;
private JLabel l;

private static String[] fileName = { "Image1.jpg", "Image2.jpg" };
private Icon[] pics = { new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(fileName[0])),
        new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(fileName[1])) };

Java() {



    super("Title");
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    cb = new JComboBox(fileName);

    cb.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {

            if(e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED)
                l.setIcon(pics[cb.getSelectedIndex()]);

        }
    });

    add(cb);
    l = new JLabel(pics [0]);
    add(l);

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can use enumeration if u want just the name and value to be used.
For Example

```
  enum label
  {
     label1(0),label2(1);

  int value;
  label(int value)
       {
       this.value=value;
       }

 }
```

and assign the comboBox,

```
   `JComboBox box=new JComboBox(label.values());`
```

if you want the value of it, 
get the label object and take the value from it
samp = box.SelectedItem().value